# Validation not triggered when data binding a number input's min / max attributes

Tags: angularjs

I have numerous number input fields that have min and max attribute values that depend on logic elsewhere in my AngularJS app, but when using data bindings within these attributes they are no longer validated by Angular, however, the HTML 5 validation still appears to pick them up.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function FirstCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.min = 10;
    $scope.max = 20;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <form name="myForm">
            <input type="number" name="one" required="required"
                   min="10" max="20" ng-model="one" />
            <input type="number" name="two" required="required"
                   min="{{ min }}" max="{{ max }}" ng-model="two" />
            <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/kriswillis/bPUVH/2/

As you can see, the validation is still handled fine in the HTML/CSS (Bootstrap) as both fields turn red when invalid, however, the submit button (handled by Angular) is not disabled when the second field is invalid. Also, there are no min and max properties in `myForm.two.$error` as there are in `myForm.one.$error`.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: There's a fix for this: [revalidate the model when min max expression values cha…](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e1bf206fff36a12b4e5851972d2f28e5cf9695b1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently we can't use {{}}s (i.e., interpolation) for the `min` and `max` fields.  I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f0c6ebc07653f6267acec898ccef5677884e3081/src/ng/directive/input.js#L528) and I found the following:

```
if (attr.min) {
  var min = parseFloat(attr.min);
```

`$interpolate` is not called, just `parseFloat`, so you'll need to specify a string that looks like a number for `min` and `max`.

Comment: So is this a bug or something? Shall an issue be opened?

Comment: Yes it's a missing feature

Comment: I think you are wrong. The interpolation for {{}} is run before this is applied.

Comment: Interpolation {{}} works with fields in Angular 5, the latest version as of today

Answer (score 22):

I wrote directives to fill the gap, ng-min and ng-max:

http://jsfiddle.net/g/s5gKC/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function isEmpty(value) {
  return angular.isUndefined(value) || value === '' || value === null || value !== value;
}

app.directive('ngMin', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngMin, function(){
                ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });
            var minValidator = function(value) {
              var min = scope.$eval(attr.ngMin) || 0;
              if (!isEmpty(value) && value < min) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ngMin', false);
                return undefined;
              } else {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ngMin', true);
                return value;
              }
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(minValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(minValidator);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('ngMax', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngMax, function(){
                ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });
            var maxValidator = function(value) {
              var max = scope.$eval(attr.ngMax) || Infinity;
              if (!isEmpty(value) && value > max) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', false);
                return undefined;
              } else {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', true);
                return value;
              }
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(maxValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(maxValidator);
        }
    };
});

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

Comment: <3 it. Saves my the hassle in writing my own directive. Thanks.

Would you submit a pull request to AngularJS?

Comment: You can try to submit it (perhaps refactor to avoid repetition first). The submit process is a bit discouraging for me on angularJS, especially when you are on windows (difficulties to run tests), already spent hours to submit a few lines PR ;) -- another PR that was closed: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1077

Comment: I'm also on Windows and not familiar with units testing JS. I searched the issue list there seems to be several closed PRs on this issue, all requiring the checklist to be cleared before submitting the PR.

Comment: Almost perfect, but `var max = scope.$eval(attr.ngMax) || Infinity;` evaluates the value 0 to Infinity.

Comment: Almost almost perfect :) But in my case, the max, or min value may change depending on other values, so I had to use the function form of watch: `scope.$watch(function () { return { ngMax: attr.ngMax } }, function () {               
                ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            }, true);`

Comment: @AkosLukacs can you provide an edit or another answer modifying the above. I'm not sure where your suggestions should go.

Comment: @Guillaume86 what is the purpose of `scope.$watch(attr.ngMin, function(){
                ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });`?

Comment: @JPCF trigger validation when minimum value changes

Comment: @AkosLukacs I don't get the difference with a simple watch, do you use {{ interpolation }}? If you use interpolation, it doesn't seem neccesary since I $eval() the attribute it's already dynamic (you can just use a scope variable or function and remove interpolation)

Comment: This doesn't set the `max` and `min` attributes of the input, which seems like an obvious miss. Add these lines to the "validator" functions: `elem.attr('min', min);`, `elem.attr('max', max);`.

Answer (score 2):

Angular appears to now support `ng-min` and `ng-max` out of the box without the necessity of writing your own directives.  See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AG2wf/159/) that is using Angular 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote a custom directive for it:

#### Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BJ98ZR?p=preview

```
.directive('validateRange', ['$parse', function($parse) {

    function link($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
        var attrRange, range = [];

        function validate(value) {
            var validMin = true, validMax = true;
            if (typeof range[0] === 'number') {
                ngModel.$setValidity('min', value >= range[0]);
                validMin = value >= range[0];
            }
            if (typeof range[1] === 'number') {
                ngModel.$setValidity('max', value <= range[1]);
                validMax = value <= range[1];
            }
            return validMin && validMax ? value : undefined;
        }

        attrRange = $attrs.validateRange.split(/,/);

        range[0] = $parse(attrRange[0] || '')($scope);
        range[1] = $parse(attrRange[1] || '')($scope);

        $scope.$watchCollection('[' + $attrs.validateRange + ']', function(values) {
            range = values;
            validate(ngModel.$viewValue);
        });

        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(validate);
        ngModel.$formatters.unshift(validate);
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        require: 'ngModel'
    };

}]);
```

Example use:

```
<form name="myform" ng-init="minvalue=0;value=1;maxvalue=2">
    Min Value:
    <input type="number" name="minvalue" required
           data-validate-range="0,value"
           ng-model="minvalue">

    Value:
    <input type="number" name="value" required
           data-validate-range="minvalue,maxvalue"
           ng-model="value">

    Max Value:
    <input type="number" name="maxvalue" required
           data-validate-range="value,false"
           ng-model="maxvalue">

    <pre>
        myform.minvalue.$error {{ myform.minvalue.$error }}
        myform.value.$error    {{ myform.value.$error }}
        myform.maxvalue.$error {{ myform.maxvalue.$error }}
    </pre>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

i have face the same problem. got success by using this directive :

```
angular.module('tech').directive('maximum', ['$parse',
  function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',

      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        if (!ctrl) return;
        attrs.maximum = true;


        var checkMax = function(n) {
          if (!n) return;

          var actualValue = ctrl.$viewValue;
          var maxValue = attrs.maximum;
          if (parseInt(actualValue) > parseInt(maxValue)) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('maximum', false);
          } else {
            ctrl.$setValidity('maximum', true);
          }
        };
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, checkMax);
        //attrs.$observe('ngModel', remind);
        attrs.$observe('maximum', checkMax);

      }
    }
  }
]);
```

i got this solution from [this](http://techhunk.com/directive-for-max-and-min-validation-in-angular-js/) website. for entire code you can go for [this](http://techhunk.com/directive-for-max-and-min-validation-in-angular-js/) website