# Why is my watch not fired in the constructor of a directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive (copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16242433/40676)

```
app.directive("dwMin", [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, modelController) {
            scope.$watch(attributes.dwMin, function () {
                modelController.$setViewValue(modelController.$viewValue);
            });

            var minValidator = function (value) {
                var min = scope.$eval(attributes.dwMin) || 0;

                if (!isEmpty(value) && value < min) {
                    modelController.$setValidity('dwMin', false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    modelController.$setValidity('dwMin', true);
                    return value;
                }
            }

            modelController.$parsers.push(minValidator);
            modelController.$formatters.push(minValidator);
        }
    }
}]);
```

And I use it like this

```
<span>min.</span><input type="text" data-ng-model="productFormData.product.MinimumDepositAmount"/>

<span>max.</span><input type="text" dw-min="{{productFormData.product.MinimumDepositAmount}}" data-ng-model="productFormData.product.MaximumDepositAmount" />
```

But when I change the min value, the watch is not fired in the dw-min directive. Why is this? What do I have to do to get the watch fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `{{ }}` from the string passed in `dw-min`. You don't need the interpolation when refer to the `model` in the attribute.

```
dw-min="productFormData.product.MinimumDepositAmount"
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Could you explain why it is working without the {{ }}? Both result in the same value, right?

Comment: @Martijn Because if you pass {{value}} like this, what you really pass is the evaluated value rather than the variable. Suppose value = "100", you will pass 100 to the controller, which is just a string.

Comment: but when the value changes from 100 to 101, the evaluated value is changed right? So whether I use {{value}} or "value", in both cases the value is changed. I'm sorry, but I don't understand why scope.$watch doesn't trigger when using {{}}.

Comment: @Martijn Correct. {{value}} will be "101", which is a string. It will lose the prototype that angular uses to track the change. If you really want to pass in {{value}}, then you need to change the $watch like this: `scope.$watch(function () {` to watch the scope change rather than a model field.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you. Bottom line is: watch a variable, not a value.