# min/max validations not working if values are changed later

Tags: angularjs

i have requirement where min value of one field depends on the input given in another field.

```
<input type="number" name="minval" class="form-control" ng-model="user.minval" 
      ng-required="true">
```

this input is used to validate another field

```
<input type="number" name="inputval" class="form-control" ng-model="user.inputval" 
     ng-required="true" min="{{user.minval}}">
```

but this is not working as expected.. if i change the "minval" later the input does not get revalidated..

i have tried setting the initial value for min from JS as was suggested in some solution but thats also not helping...

[PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/vc9Fn8k3KKUauzwRouGm?p=preview)

Comment: What do you want to happen if the original min value of the first input becomes lower than the second input value?

Comment: With much googling, I have found a very helpful SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656617/validation-not-triggered-when-data-binding-a-number-inputs-min-max-attributes

Comment: i think i don't need to answer your first comment.. the link is the answer to the problem i was facing..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use ng-min/ng-max directives

```
app.directive('ngMin', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngMin, function(){
                if (ctrl.$isDirty) ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });

            var isEmpty = function (value) {
               return angular.isUndefined(value) || value === "" || value === null;
            }

            var minValidator = function(value) {
              var min = scope.$eval(attr.ngMin) || 0;
              if (!isEmpty(value) && value < min) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ngMin', false);
                return undefined;
              } else {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ngMin', true);
                return value;
              }
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(minValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(minValidator);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('ngMax', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngMax, function(){
                if (ctrl.$isDirty) ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });
            var maxValidator = function(value) {
              var max = scope.$eval(attr.ngMax) || Infinity;
              if (!isEmpty(value) && value > max) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', false);
                return undefined;
              } else {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', true);
                return value;
              }
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(maxValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(maxValidator);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks those work great. Just one addition, if you use the required-attribute in combination with these directives the field gets marked as invalid immediatly, which isn't very user friendly. You can fix this by checking if the field is dirty in  the watch `if(ctrl.$isDirty) ...` and only doing the setViewValue then.

Comment: @akiro actually i had done that in the code, forgot to update the answer. thanks for the input anyways.

Comment: Seriously?, you want to use watch for that?... http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/removing-the-unneeded-watches/

Comment: hey, isEmpty() is not defined

Comment: This solution first appeared here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656617/validation-not-triggered-when-data-binding-a-number-inputs-min-max-attributes  Note that ng-min and ng-max are now supported by Angular without the need to write your own directives.

Comment: I don't know why but `scope.$eval(attr.ngMax)` evaluates to `undefined` so this code silently fails when attribute is a number.

Answer (score 2):

I've developed a couple of directives that actually **restrict the user from setting an invalid value** instead of simply throwing an error when an invalid value is provided.

These directives also do not require ngModel (though I doubt you would use them without) and what's really cool is that **it will wrap the value around to the min/max if both settings are provided!**

I've tried to simplify the directives as much as possible to make them easier for our readers.

Here is a JSFiddle of the whole thing: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/xqeznjmg/1/)

And here are the directives:

```
app.directive('ngMin', function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            function validate(){
                if(element
                && element[0]
                && element[0].localName === 'input'
                && isNumber(attrs.ngMin)
                && isNumber(element[0].value)
                && parseFloat(element[0].value) < parseFloat(attrs.ngMin)){
                    if(isNumber(attrs.ngMax)){
                        element[0].value = parseFloat(attrs.ngMax);
                        if(attrs.hasOwnProperty("ngModel"))
                            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, parseFloat(attrs.ngMax));
                    }
                    else {
                        element[0].value = parseFloat(attrs.ngMin);
                        if(attrs.hasOwnProperty("ngModel"))
                            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, parseFloat(attrs.ngMin));
                    }
                }
            }
            scope.$watch(function(){
                return attrs.ngMin + "-" + element[0].value;
            }, function(newVal, oldVal){
                if(newVal != oldVal)
                    validate();
            });
            validate();
        }
    };
});
app.directive('ngMax', function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            function validate(){
                if(element
                && element[0]
                && element[0].localName === 'input'
                && isNumber(attrs.ngMax)
                && isNumber(element[0].value)
                && parseFloat(element[0].value) > parseFloat(attrs.ngMax)){
                    if(isNumber(attrs.ngMin)){
                        element[0].value = parseFloat(attrs.ngMin);
                        if(attrs.hasOwnProperty("ngModel"))
                            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, parseFloat(attrs.ngMin));
                    }
                    else {
                        element[0].value = parseFloat(attrs.ngMax);
                        if(attrs.hasOwnProperty("ngModel"))
                            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, parseFloat(attrs.ngMax));
                    }
                }
            }
            scope.$watch(function(){
                return attrs.ngMax + "-" + element[0].value;
            }, function(newVal, oldVal){
                if(newVal != oldVal)
                    validate();
            });
            validate();
        }
    };
});
```

...**also**, you will need this little helper function as well:

```
function isNumber(n){
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

To invoke these directives, just set them on an input box where `type="number"`:

```
<input ng-model="myModel" ng-min="0" ng-max="1024" />
```

And that should do it!

When you provide both an `ngMin` and `ngMax`, these directive will wrap the value around, so that when your value becomes less than `ngMin`, it will be set to `ngMax`, and vice-versa.

If you only provide `ngMin` or `ngMax`, the input value will simply be capped at these values.

I prefer this method of preventing bad values rather than alerting the user that they have entered a bad value.