# input[max={{number}}] issue very odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I sunk way too much time into fixing this and i'm still not too sure what to make of it.

**The issue:**

I have an input tag `<input type="number" max="{{ theMax }}">` with a dynamic max value that should be set on the template load.

The max tag will prevent you from going above that number when you click the little up/down arrow icons in the input box, but not if you type it in.

---

**On my local**, if I typed in a number higher than the maximum value I was still able to read that value from the input fine.

**On my server** however (which has the exact same codebase), when I typed in something above the value and queried the input for it, it would give me undefined.

---

Both behaviours could make sense (I'm not sure what the actual spec is supposed to be with the max attribute) it's the oddness of the inconsistency that bewilders me (same browser and everything).

At first i'm thinking it was some kind of race condition and perhaps because `{{ theMax }}` is dynamically set perhaps the live code was slower at fetching it or something, but the fact is it still recognises the max value because the input value only returns undefined if you put something it it that is above the max.

What could explain this inconsistency? Is there something obvious or perhaps something in the rest of my code that's having this effect?

Note: yes, same browser used for both tests.

Thanks

Comment: How are you serving the file locally, just opening in a browser from the filesystem or running some local server?

Comment: Need to check this.   Are the browsers the same version (you only mention "the same", so we have to clarify)?  Are there plugins or addons in one environment that might provide a different take on how to read out of range inputs?  And I would like to know your method for querying the inputs.

Comment: I also thought that some kind of race condition cause your problem like you did. For confirming it, would you like to try to replace some static max value instead of dynamic value?

Comment: @NicholasSmith running on a node server on both the live and my local.

Comment: @irysius literally the exact same browser, didn't even close the window, when I say querying the inputs there is a directive (quite complex actually) that handles it.

Comment: @yazaki chrome latest version, static max value did seem to work fine

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to this issue or not, but came up in my search.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656617/validation-not-triggered-when-data-binding-a-number-inputs-min-max-attributes

Comment: Thank you your testing about static max value. Which value, I mean undefined or input value, did it return when you use static max value?
I think the value which you got when using static max value is correct and our goal. Along with that, race condition seems to cause your problem. Therefore I will post my recommend as "Answer".

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use dynamic max value because ng-max doesn't watch the change of value after link(or compile) function.

If you need to use dynamic max value, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831259/min-max-validations-not-working-if-values-are-changed-later) could help you.