# setting the max value to be entered in my input[number]

Tags: angularjs

First I get the max value here

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputAddress" class="col-md-6">Cost Per Case</label>
         <div class="col-md-12"><input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter cost/case."
            ng-model="purchase.cost" required>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Then I set the max using the input value above, here

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputAddress" class="col-md-6">Discount Per Case</label>
    <div class="col-md-12"><input type="number" name="discountpercase" max="{{purchase.cost}}" step="0.01" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter discount/case."
    ng-model="purchase.discount" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

With these codes, my form will still be valid even though I enter a number more than the max.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656617/validation-not-triggered-when-data-binding-a-number-inputs-min-max-attributes

Comment: Thanks for answering I think I really need to make a directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-max directive would not watch the value updated later. If you want to use dynamic max value, you need to write your custom directive. If you intend to do, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831259/min-max-validations-not-working-if-values-are-changed-later) could help you.