# HTML 5 / Angular - Form validation for number field

Tags: angularjs, html, validation

I am having a problem with form validation in HTML 5.

In my HTML I have this.

```
<input class="form-control" name="max_count" type="number" min="1" ng-model="vm.count" required>
```

Its a `NUMBER` field and `MIN` is `1`.

I have this in my angular controller,

```
if (vm.dataForm.$valid) {
    // do my logic
} else {
    alert ("Errors in Form");
}
```

### Now the Question

I type `0` in the text box. Since the `min` is `1` it automatically set the value to `1`. (which is OK). Now I click the `Submit` button.

After that I get the `alert`.

Basically even though it updates the value from `0` to `1`, the form validation happens for the value `0`.

How can I validate form with the values currently in the text field?

Comment: fiddle/plunkr please?

Comment: Is the form named dataForm?

Comment: Can you show the function which replace the value? You're probably only setting the viewValue and not the modelValue.

Comment: @user449689, Yes.

Comment: @Matheno, Actually I do not have any function to replace the value. I only set `min` to `1`. When I type `0` it automatically changes to `1`.

Comment: That's quite odd. When I simulate it, the 0 keeps intact but the input field in invalid. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10428/

Comment: It's definitely not default behaviour for angular to replace the value, it simply puts it in an invalid state.

Comment: I think you should follow this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831259/min-max-validations-not-working-if-values-are-changed-later

I have tried it and its worked