# How to pass a scope variable to a native input min attribute in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm working with Angular 1.5. I'm trying to accomplish something quite trivial. Apologies if this sounds a bit off as backend is more my fortè. What I'm trying to do is pass a scope variable to an input attribute.  Is this a known issue?

```
angular.module('CompDirective',
    ['ngMaterial']
).directive('pitchButton', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            campaign: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/static/html/compensation.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.minCompensation = 100;
        }
)
```

and in my html.

```
<input
    type="number"
    ng-model='fields.monetary_compensation'
    name="compensation" required
    ng-pattern='/^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/'
    placeholder="Compensation"
    min="minCompensation"
></input>
```

Echoing out minCompensation works as expected but the param min with minCompensation is not validating which leads me to believe that there is an issue with the input directive's min param being able to recognize scope variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` is not in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input), so I'm guessing it doesn't accept an angular expression.

You need to interpolate the value as in `<input ... min="{{minCompensation}}" />`

Alternatively, you can create your own [`ng-min` and `ng-max` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831259/min-max-validations-not-working-if-values-are-changed-later).

Comment: odd. Why would it then work with a hardcoded value? Anyway, I'll accept this but also post my own solution

Comment: Because `min` is an HTML5 attribute, not an Angular directive. In the solution you posted, you're using an Angular directive to dynamically set the HTML5 attribute - which is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The scope value needs to be interpolated/evaluated. So the [ng-attr](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) attribute will evaluate and bind the appropriate value in addition to bracketting the variable.

Code

```
<input
    type="number"
    ng-model='fields.monetary_compensation'
    name="compensation" 
    placeholder="Compensation"
    ng-attr-min="{{minCompensation}}"
></input>
```