# How to initialize the value of an input[range] using AngularJS when value is over 100

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-directive, range

I try to initialize a slider using AngularJS, but the cursor show 100 when the value is over 100.

Setting the value 150 in a range [50,150] fails with this code :

```html
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  angular.module('App', ['App.controllers']);
  angular.module('App.controllers', []).controller('AppController', function($scope) {
   $scope.min = 50;
   $scope.max = 150;
   $scope.value = 150;
  });  
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController" >
 {{min}}<input ng-model="value" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" type="range" />{{max}}<br/>
 value:{{value}}
</body>
</html>
```

The cursor is badly placed (it show 100 instead of 150).
How to display the cursor to its correct place ?

An explanation of what occurs could be on [this forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/zIqGljo3z4Y/JSVTbkippD4J)

**Update**
This bug is reported as issue [#6726](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6726)

**Update**
The issue [#14982](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14982) is closed by the [Pull Request 14996](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14996) and solve the issue see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38927038/3102264).

Comment: I think what you have is better, check this answer as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656617/validation-not-triggered-when-data-binding-a-number-inputs-min-max-attributes

Comment: There are some interesting discussions related to this here as well. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2404

Comment: Thanks  I read this both links several times, and some others, but I did not catch if this is an expected behaviour or a bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/a272a3c0bd88b6df354102dc059a0d14b5b22675), the initial code give the expected result.
Using release [1.6.0](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.min.js) allow to original code to show slider correctly :

```html
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  angular.module('App', ['App.controllers']);
  angular.module('App.controllers', []).controller('AppController', function($scope) {
   $scope.min = 50;
   $scope.max = 150;
   $scope.value = 150;
  });  
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController" >
 {{min}}<input ng-model="value" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" type="range" />{{max}}<br/>
 value:{{value}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

After searches and tries , a possible way is to define a custom directive :

```html
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  angular.module('App', ['App.controllers']);
  angular.module('App.controllers', []).controller('AppController', function($scope) {
   $scope.min = 50;
   $scope.max = 150;
   $scope.value = 150;
  }).directive('ngMin', function() {
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) { elem.attr('min', attr.ngMin); }
   };
  }).directive('ngMax', function() {
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) { elem.attr('max', attr.ngMax); }
   };
  });  
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController" >
 {{min}}<input ng-model="value" ng-min="{{min}}" ng-max="{{max}}" type="range" />{{max}}<br/>
 value:{{value}}
</body>
</html>
```

Even it is working this is a non standard extension in order to manage a very basic use case.

Comment: I've seen similar solutions, maybe the exact solution elsewhere. But, this one made the most sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this new one.

You can configure angular to make it interpolate these values.
And you can use your initial code after that ...

Isn't it magic ?

Use this code only once in your app. Once angular is configured, it will be working for all the future ranges you will use.

```html
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('App', ['App.controllers']);
        angular.module('App.controllers', [])
        /* Modify angular to make it interpolate min and max, for ngModel when type = range */
        .config(['$provide', function($provide) {
            $provide.decorator('ngModelDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
                var ngModel = $delegate[0], controller = ngModel.controller;
                ngModel.controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$injector', function(scope, element, attrs, $injector) {
                    if ('range' === attrs.type) {
                        var $interpolate = $injector.get('$interpolate');
                        attrs.$set('min', $interpolate(attrs.min || '')(scope));
                        attrs.$set('max', $interpolate(attrs.max || '')(scope));
                        $injector.invoke(controller, this, {
                            '$scope': scope,
                            '$element': element,
                            '$attrs': attrs
                        });
                    }
                }];
                return $delegate;
             }]);
         }])
         .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
             $scope.min = 50;
             $scope.max = 150;
             $scope.value = 150;
         });   
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController" >
 {{min}}<input ng-model="value" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" type="range"/>{{max}}<br/>
 value:{{value}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. The cleanest then, is to configure angular engine directly. I edited my answer, try this new snippet ... and tell me...

Comment: I unaccept your answer because it works by side effects. Replacing `attrs.$set('max', $interpolate(attrs.max || '')(scope));` with  `attrs.$set('max', '');` sill trig the update. It doesnot works with 2 sliders and  this bug is referenced in angularJs issues https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6726

Comment: You are right, the pb was about the cursor value and not the range setup. Sorry about that, I did not get it by the time. But for a reason I don't really understand my workaround still does work : http://plnkr.co/edit/VuqxFv4Ni72TYbK00dqp?p=preview (even with two sliders)

Answer (score 2):

My lazy way of addressing this bug was to divide the min/max and step values by 100. So 300 becomes 3.0, etc. and values fall below 100. Then I multiply things back as needed.