# How to set range validation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set range validation i.e i want salary should be between 100000-20000000. I used ng-min and ng-max. But still its not throwing error message. here is what i have done. Its only checking number validation.

```
<input ng-model="name2" name="name2" type="text" class="zoomIn" ng-min="100000" ng-max="20000000" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" placeholder="Your Annual Net Profit" required>
<div ng-messages="step5form.name2.$error">
<div ng-message="min">Please enter a value between 100000 and 20000000.</div>
<div ng-message="max">Please enter a value between 100000 and 20000000.</div>
<div ng-message="pattern">Annual net profit cannot be characters.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use ng-minlength="number" ng-maxlength="number" from angular docs

Comment: i tried using minlength and maxlength but then it is not accepting the value between that range  and its disabling the next button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation not triggered when data binding a number input's min / max attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656617/validation-not-triggered-when-data-binding-a-number-inputs-min-max-attributes)

Comment: @nglover he is using number validation then type="number" is must. ng-minlength and ng-maxlength will checkcharacters length not numbe. please go through docs carefully.

Comment: i also tried the number type but then its showing the up and down arrow in the input box which i dont want

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try to read [AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api) docs first.

Here you are using **type="text"** and for type text there are **ng-minlength** and **ng-maxlength** whereas for **type="number"** there are **min** and **max** properties.

```
<input ng-model="name2" name="name2" type="number" class="zoomIn" min="2" max="4" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" placeholder="Your Annual Net Profit" required>
<div ng-messages="step5form.name2.$error">
<div ng-message="min">Please enter a value between 100000 and 20000000.</div>
<div ng-message="max">Please enter a value between 100000 and 20000000.</div>
<div ng-message="pattern">Annual net profit cannot be characters.</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

**Updated** : 
To remove input spinners add this css

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Comment: but by putting type= number it shows up and down arrow in the input field.

Comment: To remove that there are ways. Just because there are spinners you cant do that. I have updated my answer please accept it if you found beneficial

Comment: i have put the css given by you but still arrows are not going

Comment: I have updated one more css try that and still you have any problem please make a plunker.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/0Og86OO2Z26IRohVGmOF?p=preview here i have created the plunk. also on changing input type to number its not throwing the error message can not accept characters. is there any way to keep input type to text and still able to display the range error message

Comment: sorry, i just checked your edited css code. and its working perfectly. thank you so much

Comment: but on putting input type to number its not throwing the error message for characters

Comment: because if you will type number it will automaticaly become invalid because its a type input number no need to show message for that.

Comment: yeah i know.. but i need to show the error message of characters

Answer (score 0):

Use in Angular way:

```
<input type="number"
       ng-model="string"
       [name="string"]
       [min="string"]
       [max="string"]
       [required="string"]
       [ng-required="string"]
       [ng-minlength="number"]
       [ng-maxlength="number"]
       [pattern="string"]
       [ng-pattern="string"]
       [ng-change="string"]>
```

[Angular Way - More detail](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

Or by Own Directory

http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/AG2wf/1/